# Can't connect to MongoDB on Docker Container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm working on a node js api and I'm using mongodb. Right now I'm facing one problem when I try to connect to the database, I'm getting this error `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`  the api is running on a docker container and the database is local, I'm not running mongo on docker container.

this is my connection string `mongodb://localhost:27017/database`

and this is my docker file

```
FROM node
RUN apk add dumb-init
ENV PORT=4000
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm ci
COPY . /usr/src/app/
USER node
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["dumb-init", "node", "/usr/src/app/app.js"]
```

**UPDATE**

Forgot to add the `docker-compose.yml`

Here it is:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.api
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "27017:27017"
    extra_hosts:
      "host.docker.internal": host-gateway
    volumes:
      - ./var/:/var
    restart: on-failure
```

Can someone tell what is wrong or what else is missing?

Comment: How are you running the container? If you're not publishing a port (`-p <host_port>:<container_port>`) the service will not be available on `localhost` on your host.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: @Iarsks I'm running the image using `docker-compose up -d`! @Phil I'm going to take a look on that question...

Answer (score 0):

Make the hostname for your connection string to mongodb
`host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`

i.e: `mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/database`

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host